# Align code in VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to align the written C++ code in VS 2010? I want after selecting a block of code to apply a combination of button press and the code to be aligned as in Eclipse or Netbeans with Java.

Comment: You mean that you want a function to fix the source indentation? Not align the actual compiled code in memory?

Comment: Just to align the code I write (and see) in a cpp file. For example to bring { } in appropriate places etc.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `Edit` -> `Advanced` -> `Format Selection`

The keyboard shortcut depends on your settings. It's <kbd>Ctrl+K+F</kbd> for me. (Under `Options` -> `Environment` -> `Keyboard` enter `Edit.FormatSelection` into the field labeled `Show commands containing` to add your own shortcut.)

Answer (score 1):

for code block : ctrl +E,F (Edit -> Advanced -> Format Selections)
for document   : ctrl +E,D (Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document)

Answer (score 0):

Try using <kbd>Ctrl+K+F</kbd> on the selected text.

Answer (score 0):

Is `Ctrl + E, D` what you're after?